# Mapping a function in Slim to '/' returns directory structure

Tags: php, html, slim

My question is much similar to this one:
[Default GET route with Slim PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568765/default-get-route-with-slim-php)
But I have a query:
Whenever I try to access (localhost/mySite), instead of executing the mapped function (mapped to '/'), I get the directory structure of my folder.
Now that is pretty obvious as I don't have any index file in my site folder.
The function doesn't even gets called. Is there anyway to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have properly setup your htaccess?

Comment: And by 'properly', what do you imply? All my other mappings are working just fine. Gets routed to my routes.php successfully, if that's what you're trying to say.

Comment: Are you on Apache? If yes, can you add your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rename `routes.php` to `index.php` you could overwrite your **DirectoryIndex** for that directory:

```
#.htaccess
#…rewrite stuff

DirectoryIndex routes.php
```

With this method you tell your Apache that `routes.php` actually is the index.